# Why won't subprocess.run execute a simple command?

Tags: python, r, cmd

I run:

```
Rscript hello_world.R
```

from my `cmd` terminal where the directory is:

```
C:\Users\Philip\OneDrive\Betting\Capra\Tennis\polgara>
```

The script runs fine.

However, I want Python to run it and have this small script located in the same directory as above:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['Rscript', 'hello_world.R'])
```

However, I get this error when I run it from VS Code:

```
Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I next tried:

```
subprocess.run(['Rscript', 'hello_world.R'], shell=True)
```

But I got:

```
'Rscript' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

For reference I've added the following to my path:

```
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.3\bin\x64
```

I've just tried running

```
Rscript hello_world.R
```

from the `cmd` terminal in VS Code which has the following directory set:

```
(polgara) C:\Users\Philip\OneDrive\Betting\Capra\Tennis\polgara>
```

This also gives the error:

```
'Rscript' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Could the `(polgara)` at the beginning be the source of my problem? I believe this is my virtual environment...?

Comment: What matters is the *current working* directory, which is **not** necessarily the same directory your code is in. That is to say, if you're in `C:/` and you run `c:/hello/something.py`, and it then tries to open `hello_world.R`, it'll look for `C:/hello_world.r`, not `c:/hello/hello_world.r` (forward-slashes used for markdown sanity)

Comment: ...whereas when you get an error about `Rscript` not being found, that means it's time to look at your `PATH` *for the specific process throwing the error*, as opposed to paying attention to general system-wide defaults. Inspect `os.environ['PATH']`. (Yes, `(polgara)` tells you you're in a virtualenv, and entering a virtualenv changes your PATH, so your active PATH is likely to differ from the system-wide defaults).

Comment: Hi @CharlesDuffy - thanks for replying. Afraid I'm pretty new to everything command line. 
How do I make sure my Python script is using the right working directory? How do I look at my ```PATH``` for a specific process throwing an error? What do you mean when you say virtualenv change my ```PATH```? What implications does that have? Are you able to give me some simple instructions on what to do? Thanks again.

Comment: Restarting the machine is overkill -- just logging out and back in would have worked. Restarting individual processes is _sometimes_ good enough too; "log all the way out" is just convenient as a way to make sure _everything_ has been started. (Processes initialize environment variables from their parents at the time when they're started; global changes don't modify an individual process's environment after-the-fact).

Comment: ...btw, to inspect your PATH from Python, `print(os.environ['PATH'])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look on:

[What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564)

It is necessary to restart Windows after a modification of **system** environment variable `Path` to make sure all processes work with updated `Path`.

In general any executable can be run from within a Python script without the usage of Windows command processor `cmd.exe` which means without using `shell=True`. But it is necessary to specify the executable with full qualified file name, i.e. drive + path + name + extension, on not being in current directory of running process which is in this case `python.exe` interpreting the Python script.

I suggest to read the Microsoft documentation for function [CreateProcessA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) and the other pages referenced on this page respectively listed on left side. All the parameters of the methods of Python module [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/subprocess.html) like `cwd` (current working directory for the subprocess) are easier to understand on having knowledge about process creation by Windows kernel.

The R script file name passed as argument to `Rscript.exe` should be specified also with full qualified file name to be found by `Rscript.exe` independent on what is the current directory of `Rscript` process.